Is there a way to restart a Faust app programmatically if the initial connection to Kafka fails?
When my Faust application starts and Kafka is not running then the Faust app terminates. Is there a way to make my app keep retrying to connect programmatically?
I tried the following:
while True:
    try:
        app.main()
    except:
        print("Restarting the app...")
        sleep(5)

but then the process fails with asyncio complaining with the following message:
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

